# Error java.lang.NullPointerException al intentar mostrar mi lista

Tags: java

Muy buenos días.
Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una clase "ListaPersonas" que me dimensiona Arreglo de tipo objeto, esta es la programación:

```
public class ListaPersonas {

private int TamañoArreglo;
private Persona ListaPersonas[];

public ListaPersonas() {
    this.TamañoArreglo = 0;
    ListaPersonas = null;
}




public int getTamaño() {
    return this.TamañoArreglo;
}



public Persona PersonaPos(int pos) {
    return ListaPersonas[pos];
}

public void setTamañoArreglo(int TamañoArreglo) {
    this.TamañoArreglo = TamañoArreglo;
}

public void GenerarLista() {
    ListaPersonas = new Persona[TamañoArreglo];
}

public void GuardarPersonas(Persona p, int pos) {
    ListaPersonas[pos] = p;
}
```

Entonces, luego en otra clase donde tengo mi JFrame, lleno la información:

```
public class VistaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private int personas = 0;
ListaPersonas lista = new ListaPersonas();
DefaultListModel mostrar = new DefaultListModel();



public VistaPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Rol.addItem("Estudiante");
    Rol.addItem("Empleado");
    Rol.addItem("Profesor");
    Contador.setText("Personas Ingresadas: 0");
    Contador1.setText("Tamaño de la BaseDeDatos: 0");
    mostrar = new DefaultListModel();
    Lista.setModel(mostrar);

}

public int AumentoPersonas() {
   int Tamaño = Integer.parseInt(Personas.getValue().toString());
   int Persona = 0;
   if(personas != Tamaño){
     Persona = personas++;
   }
  return Persona;
}





public void GuardarPersonas(Persona p, int pos) {
    lista.GuardarPersonas(p, pos);
}

 public int PersonasRegistradas() {
    return personas;
}

public int TamañoPersonas() {
    return lista.getTamaño();
}


public void LimpiarCampos() {
    Personas.setValue(0);
    Rol.setSelectedItem("");
    mostrar.clear();
}
```

Tengo un método que se llama TamañoPersonas que en teoría me devuelve el tamaño que tiene la lista, luego cuando voy a llenarla, tengo lo siguiente:

```
 private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (TamañoPersonas() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < TamañoPersonas(); i++) {
            mostrar.add(i, "" + lista.PersonaPos(i).MostrarDatos());
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Primero debes realizar el registro.");
    }


}
```

El problema es que me está tirando el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Paquetes.VistaPrincipal.jButton4ActionPerformed(VistaPrincipal.java:280)
at Paquetes.VistaPrincipal.access$300(VistaPrincipal.java:10)
at Paquetes.VistaPrincipal$4.actionPerformed(VistaPrincipal.java:137)
```

Será que no me está dimensionando el vector de la lista al comienzo? porque ya probé de todo, intenté con un ArrayList y no con un vector normal, también intenté ponerle como parámetro el tamaño del vector, esto para corroborar que no me estuviera dando un vector de 0 posiciones, pero nada de esto sirve, alguna idea de qué puedo estar haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te marca la linea 280, revisa que tienes ahi, y el error es de tipo NullPointerException, algun dato va en null

Comment: Te recomendaría usar List en lugar de arreglos, asi puedes usar .size para el numero de datos y .get para recorrer una posición especifica

Comment: El problema es que no me lo está registrando por algún motivo, si, me tira null el dato, ya cambié eso, pero ahora me lo toma como si no lo estuviera registrando...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en esto pero intentaré ayudarte y de esta forma practicar.
En los lenguajes de programación no deberías nunca crear cosas con "ñ" u caracteres propios de el español como en la variable: TamañoArreglo; es mejor poner TamanioArreglo y la primera letra siempre en minuscula tamanioArreglo (se llama Camel Case) y en las variables siempre primera minuscula (En las clases y objetos si empieza en mayuscula).
Lo del nullPointerException es que esta accediendo a un nulo en algun lugar del array. Para recorrer los arrays en el for escribe:

```
// ejemplo de arreglo
Object[] array = new Object[10];
//...
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
// aqui se puede referir al objeto con arreglo[i];
}
```

con .length recorrerá el array completo

tambien puedes usar un foreach

for (Object o : arreglo){
// en cada iteración "o" se refiere a un objeto del arreglo para todos objetos en el
//arreglo
}